# How to configure a file system on a data disk in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, rhel

We are creating a new VM with terraform in Azure and a data disk is added. When the OS, in this case RHEL, is installed, we can see the LUN as /dev/sdc. How can we create a partition (one primary) and a file system (ext4) on the LUN and how can we update /etc/fstab, making use of terraform? We would like to avoid doing manual work, by logging in via SSH to the machine, running fdisk/mkfs.ext4.

Answer (score 0):

Use Terraform [Local-Exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) or [Remote-Exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html)

Comment: Looking at the suggestion, this is like embedding shell code (e.g. bash) into terraform. I have not tested this, but it seems like a conflict with the whole philosophy of infra-as-code.
In parallel, I have found something in Ansible to create a partition and a file system, update fstab and mount it: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/mount_module.html

This is working good, and I wonder if HashiCorp will develop something similar.